# Can we interchange Trace and Integral because both are linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics

Is it true if we write the following and interchange Trace and Integral operators

$$
\int_a^b
Tr(r(x)r(x)^T)dx
=
Tr(\int_a^br(x)r(x)^Tdx)
$$

where $r(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you mention the other form of integral, because I am not aware of those? Also, an example that it is not true?

Comment: sry, I deleted my previous comments, Im not sure what kind of operator is the trace in this context. If the operator is bounded then yes, if not you would need additional conditions, depending on the behavior of the operator

Comment: @Masacroso: Trace operator in my problem is just the summation of elements of the product $r(x)r(x)^T$ nothing more. It is the Trace defining for matrices. And it is bounded because  $r(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Seed I see, I understood the notation $v^T$ to be a vertical vector, but I realized that it is more natural to be the other way around, so we just write $Ax$ as the action of a matrix $A$ over a vector $x$, this was my source of confusion. Then yes, the trace operator is linear and bounded, and consequently continuous, so your swap holds.